# What is expected color of an object?

Tags: probability-distributions

There is a set of n objects $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n\}$ each having color $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_n\}$ respectively. Now a random subset of this objects is selected and painted with some random color from set $\{d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_k\}$. What is the expected color of each object after this procedure?

I am new to this topic so please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a simplified variant of this current contest problem: http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/LEPAINT

Comment: @HenningMakholm I asked for the explanation of the test cases given in the problem several times but no one,not even admin answered.